# Are strings Drop or Copy?

Tags: rust, ownership

I'm learning about Rust's ownership. My tests show that string literals are copied on variable assignment while `String` instances are moved. Does that mean that `String` is `Drop` while string literals are `Copy`?

**variable_assign_test.rs**

```
// variable assign test,

// assign variable on stack to another,
fn test_stack_assign() {
    let x = 5;
    let y = x; // data duplicated on stack,
    println!("x = {}, y = {}", x, y); // it's ok,
}

// assign variable on heap to another,
fn test_heap_assign() {
    let s1 = String::from("hello");
    let s2 = s1;    // now s1 is invalid, should not use it any more,
    // println!("{}", s1); // this won't compile,
    println!("s2 = {}", s2); // it's ok,
}

fn test_tuple_assign() {
    let pa = (1, 2);
    let pb = pa;
    println!("pa = {:?}, pb = {:?}", pa, pb); // it's ok,

    // tuple that contains string literal,
    let name_monica = "monica";
    let monica = (11, name_monica);
    let monica2 = monica;
    println!("monica = {:?}, monica2 = {:?}", monica, monica2);

    // tuple that contains String instance,
    let name_eric = String::from("eric");
    let eric = (12, name_eric);
    let eric2 = eric; // eric is invalid now,
    // println!("eric = {:?}, eric = {:?}", eric, eric2); // this won't compile,
}

fn main() {
    test_stack_assign();
    test_heap_assign();
    test_tuple_assign();
}
```

Compile with `rustc variable_assign_test.rs -o a.out` and run with `./a.out`

If the last line of `test_tuple_assign()` is uncommented, it will get an error `value used here after move` for the variable `eric`.

Comment: Thank you, I think your question is more understandable :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Yes**.

To be clear, all immutable references (`&T`) are `Copy`, while the mutable ones (`&mut T`) are move only. `&'static str`, the type of string literals, is just one special case of `&T`, an immutable reference, and therefore is `Copy`.

On the other hand, a `String` instance is the single owner of a dynamically allocated buffer for its content. This prevents it from being `Copy` (single owner) and requires it to implement `Drop` (to free the dynamically allocated buffer).

In details, though, `String` does not implement `Drop` directly, but instead is a wrapper around a `Vec<u8>` which itself implements `Drop`. The behavior is identical, it's just that the `Drop` implementation of `String` is auto-generated, whereas the one from `Vec<u8>` is [manually written](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/collections/vec.rs.html#1921).